# How do I make wx.TextCtrl multi-line text update smoothly?

Tags: python, wxpython, wx.textctrl

I'm working on an GUI program, and I use AppendText to update status in a multi-line text box(made of wx.TextCtrl). I noticed each time there's a new line written in this box, instead of smoothly adding this line to the end, the whole texts in the box just disappear(not in real, just visually) and I have to click the scroll button to check the newly updated/written status line. Why this happening? Should I add some styles? Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Here's my sample code:

```
import wx
import thread
import time

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, id = -1, title = "Testing", pos=(350, 110), size=(490,530), style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.StartButton = wx.Button(parent = panel, id = -1, label = "Start", pos = (110, 17), size = (50, 20))
        self.MultiLine = wx.TextCtrl(parent = panel, id = -1, pos = (38, 70), size = (410, 90), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_AUTO_URL)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, self.StartButton)

    def OnStart(self, event):
        self.StartButton.Disable()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.LongRunning, ())

    def LongRunning(self):
        Counter = 1
        while True:
            self.MultiLine.AppendText("Hi," + str(Counter) + "\n")
            Counter = Counter + 1
            time.sleep(2)


class TestApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.TestFrame = TestFrame()
        self.TestFrame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.TestFrame)
        return True

def main():
    App = TestApp(redirect = False)
    App.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the `Refresh()` method on the `textCtrl`

**Update:**

A question has already been asked regarding this problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153989/how-do-i-get-the-scroll-position-range-from-a-wx-textctrl-control-in-wxpython/155781#155781) is the answer which pretty much solves it, -its not perfect but maybe you can improve on it...

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/browse_thread/thread/afd3c81d07c31c5d/25c98859f4ee1449) is a thread from the wxpython mailing list regarding the problem which may also be of interest to you.

Comment: It's not working... I still get blank and have to use the scrollbar to check status...

Comment: If you can add a runnable sample, then it shouldn't take me or someone else long or figure outs what wrong. Without code its a guessing game!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, see my updated answer for a link that pretty much solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
self.logs = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=-1, value='', pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                            size=(-1,300),
                            style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
self.logs.AppendText(text + "\n")
```