# WxPython Add new text line to WxTextCtrl causes to lose curernt location

Tags: wxpython

When printing constantly to WxTextCtrl, how do i disable a new print causing the jump to the end of the TextCtrl?

```
self.command_line = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
```

I have build a LOG TextCtrl to a DUT.

When i scroll up, it keeps "jumping" back to the bottom of TextCtrl on every new message. how can i disable that when i scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `SetInsertionPoint` and `GetSelection`.
This seems to do what you want.
Note that checking the `end == pos` and resetting the insertion point, allows you to click at the bottom of the text, which will then continue with the normal scrolling, when text is added later.

```
import wx
class MyApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,title=title, size=(500, 515))
        sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button = wx.Button(self, id = 1,label = "Add Text")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, button)
        self.note = "This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap. This is a fairly long text string that I would like to wrap."
        self.noteCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,wx.ID_ANY,value=self.note,style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.VSCROLL,size=(50, 400))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnText, self.noteCtrl)
        sizer.Add(self.noteCtrl,1)
        sizer.Add(button,0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.noteCtrl.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self,evt):
        end = self.noteCtrl.GetLastPosition()
        pos = self.noteCtrl.GetInsertionPoint()
        if end == pos:
            self.noteCtrl.SetSelection(0,0)
        selected1, selected2 = self.noteCtrl.GetSelection()
        self.noteCtrl.AppendText("\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n")
        self.noteCtrl.AppendText("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n")
        self.noteCtrl.AppendText("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n")
        self.noteCtrl.AppendText("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxX\n")

        if selected1 != 0:
            self.noteCtrl.SetInsertionPoint(selected1)

    def OnText(self,evt):
        selected1, selected2 = self.noteCtrl.GetSelection()
        print (selected1, selected2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame = MyApp(None, title = "My Application")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks , but now it jumps to the top on every new message.

Comment: My goal is to be able to read some text from the log while it continues printing more lines.I basically scroll and what it to stay focused on that part.

Comment: Then set the insertion point to the Scroll position before you appended to it. This should be available via `GetScrollPosition()`, although it fails miserably using wxpython4, as it falls over stating that the "window is not scrollable" in spite of the fact that it clearly has a vertical scrollbar. You might get more mileage from a scrolled panel.

Comment: thanks, ended up tweaking this code : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153989/how-do-i-get-the-scroll-position-range-from-a-wx-textctrl-control-in-wxpython)